# How do I use a stack built haskell package in an IHaskell Notebook?

Tags: haskell, jupyter, haskell-stack, ihaskell

I can successfully open and use the IHaskell demo notebook. I also have some haskell code that I wrote and which builds with stack and for which `stack ghci` gives me an interactive venue for using my functions and data types. How do I combine these two so that I can use my module within an IHaskell notebook?